# How to start a new vim instance?

Tags: vim

I am working on Windows 7 and GVim 7.3.  If I already have one Vim instance running, how to start up another Vim instance, preferably by using some Vim commands?

Currently I do this in the existing vim:

```
:!gvim
```

But a Windows CMD window is opened, along with the new Vim window. It's a little annoying.

Are there other (more elegant) ways to start a new vim instance? Thanks.

Comment: Probably but this is already quite eloquent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Question is, why would you even *want* another instance? Working with [buffers](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-buffers) and [tabs](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-tabs) is usually much more efficient than having multiple windows floating around.

However, if you *really* want a new window, start it with

```
:!start gvim.exe
```

which suppresses the command line window.

Comment: + 1. You can open a new window for editing within the gvim window using CTRL + w + n

Comment: I keep a bunch of files(notes, references, todos, emails, books, etc) opened all day in a Vim instance, separated from the one I am doing coding and stuff.

Comment: @NehaKaranjkar that is not the same kind of window the OP was talking about. To avoid the console window from popping up, use `:!start gvim.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

You can map this, i.e. ad to your `.vimrc`

```
map <C-S-n> :!gvim<CR>
```

Then pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> will open new window.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the Windows cmd window annoying you, use:

```
:!start gvim
```

Comment: thanks. Michael replied to my question first, so I accepted his answer.